# How do I delete the whole row with a null value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

How do I delete the row with empid null?

Comment: Delete from yourTable where empid is null???

Comment: i tried this query 
 delete from compemp where @empid=null;

Comment: delete from table_name where empid is null

Comment: voting to close this question since no example of what they've tried has been provided.

Comment: There is no column called `@empid`.  You have to remove the `@` from your delete and the correct syntax is `IS NULL`, not `=NULL`.

Comment: That is because nothing ever equals NULL. NULL is unknown, that is why you have to use IS NULL. You could also use "where comp = 200" given your sample data.

Comment: @sean lange it worked thanks. equals null was the issue. is null worked..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM tablename 
WHERE empid IS NULL
```

Comment: Why people are down voting. This is actually the correct answer for his question

Comment: Not my downvote but I assume it is because you didn't provide any explanation. Code only answers are generally not very good because they are incomplete.